# Google Cloud - Unable to access private CloudSQL database in one VPC network from another VPC network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, vpc, hashicorp-vault

Our setup includes
 - A primary VPC where the we have compute engines and Postgres databases that are created with private IP. Let's refer it as `main-network`,
 - Vault deployed in it's own VPC and accessible via Loadbalancer (as per the best practice). Let's refer it as `vault-network`.

Within `main-network` compute instances are able to access the DBs with the private IP as the DBs where created with `main-network` as the parent network while creation. Looking at various VPC details, it seems like the creation process auto creates private-service-access as described [in the docs.](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access).

The problem - For Vault [database secret-engine](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/postgresql.html), Vault needs to be able to access the DB to dynamically generate secrets. 
I have tried creating VPC network peering between `main-network` and `vault-network` and verified (via netcat) that I can successfully reach machines in the `main-network` from machines in the `vault-network`.

However, I cannot reach the DB instances from the nodes in `vault-network`.

Is it possible to share the access to private-service with a peered vpc network?

I don't want to make the DBs public unless it's the only way.

Comment: VPC Peering is not transitive. This means you can connect from VPC A to VPC B. You cannot connect from VPC A thru VPC B to VPC C where Cloud SQL is located. You will need to peer Cloud SQL to VPC A.

Comment: Peering vault-network to CloudSql network was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as there is no option to select that particular cloudSql network anywhere. Would appreciate if you can add the steps

Comment: I explained what the problem is so that you would understand why.  Review Guillaume's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to the Google support for our account and asked them about this problem and they confirmed that it's not possible to have a transitive VPC peering

> VPC peering is not transitive, this scenario is not possible using VPC peering between the VPC networks:
>
> Cloud SQL <[VPC Peering]> VPC “main-network” <[VPC Peering]> VPC “vault-network”.

Creating a shared VPC defeats the purpose of creating a separate network in the first place as it would make the vault nodes directly accessible in the shared VPC.

The Google guy suggested to create a VPN:

> As a workaround, you could create a VPN between the VPC networks “main-network” and “vault-network”:
>
> Cloud SQL <[VPC Peering]> VPC “main-network” <[Cloud VPN]> VPC “vault-network”.

I need some time to think if we want to go down this path or not.

For now, I have whitelisted the NAT IP of the vault cluster in the `settings.ip_configuration.authorized_networks` configuration of the database instance to give access to the vault network.
The down side of this is that the database has a public IP now which isn't necessarily bad as the firewall blocks public access to it.

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.

Comment: I have the same problem now.  I need to access the db from an application VPC, peered with the VPC where db is configured.  All our VPCs are in the 10.128.0.0 range, an RFC1918 address range.  What did you mean by the NAT IP of `vault_cluster`?  Are you referring to the CloudNAT address (the internet gw of the VPC)?  Did you have to assign a public IP for the DB and connect to that from the VPC?   I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: @donnie, forget the Vault part. For your VPC have you done this https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-services-access?

Comment: Yes.  I can connect to the Cloud SQL from the VMs hosted in the same VPC over a private address.  I have not configured a public address for the Cloud SQL.  Finally, I configured a Cloud SQL Auth Proxy in the VPC to enable connections from other VPCs.  This Auth Proxy will be the entry point for my management tools like pgadmin and others.

Answer (score 1):

Because your Cloud SQL is not in your VPC, but a VPC peering is performed between the Cloud SQL and your VPC, you can't reach another VPC network by peering. As John said, it's named transitivity and described in the [VPC peering restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#restrictions)

> Only directly peered networks can communicate. Transitive peering is not supported. In other words, if VPC network N1 is peered with N2 and N3, but N2 and N3 are not directly connected, VPC network N2 cannot communicate with VPC network N3 over VPC Network Peering.

Sadly, you can't create a peering between your Cloud SQL and the VPC network (your vault-network) of another project as suggested by John. I see only 2 solutions to solve this

- set up a pass trough VM that only forward the traffic. Micro VM is enough for this, but you have to maintain it, to take care of the high availability, (...)
- Set up a [shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) whith your 2 projects inside. Set up your Cloud SQL private IP into the share VPC subnet.

Comment: I think I understand conceptually what you mean by setting up a pass through VM but I am not sure what is the best way to go forward with it. If you have experience with it, can you share how you did it?
Setting up the vault-network into the shared VPC is undesirable as it would make vault-nodes directly accessible and it defeats the purpose of creating the separate networks in the first place.